# IQueryable<T>.GroupBy() On Reference Type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using Linq to SQL I'm writing queries that are taking advantage of the IQueryable.GroupBy method.

Even though my query involves many tables and left joins lets say for illustration that we are only working with two tables. TableA has a one to many relationship to TableB.

```
var queryResults = from db.TableA
       .Join(db.TableB, tA => tA.ID, tB => tB.TableA_ID, (ta, tb) => tb)
       .GroupBy(tb => tb.TableA);
```

This will give me an

```
<IQueryable<IGrouping<TableA, TableB>>
```

On the surface this seems to work however I'm worried because I'm calling the GroupBy method and passing in a reference type for the keySelector argument.

Please help me understand why this is or isn't a safe thing to do.

Comment: That doesnt seem to make sense; consider the SQL version of that. You can't really group by an entire table; you group by a specific column.

Comment: If I look at the SQL this generates it is a bit weird. It basically does a sub select of TableA and TableB and then joins the results of that back on TableA. I assure you though that it is returning IGroupings of TableA as the key with all correct TableBs as the values.

Comment: Yes, but what column is it doing the join back to on TableA?

Comment: It's an inner join. TableA.ID = SubQueryResult.TableA_ID

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're trying to do, but I think you might want to use comprehension syntax here to make it easier to write/understand.  In particular, do your grouping *after* you've done whatever joins or other operations you want to do instead of mixing them together.

```
var query = ... (can be chained methods, whatever)

var grouped = from row in query
              group row by row.SomeProperty;
```

Then you'll likely have an easier time (I would think) writing and reasoning about the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var queryResults =
    from ta in db.TableA
    join tb in db.TableB on ta.ID equals tb.TableA_ID
    group tb by ta;
```

And yes, this is safe to do on reference types. The query generated by linq-to-sql has nothing to do with reference types - it's just SQL.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: @svick - Sorry. How's that now?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()`. These methods are used during grouping in LINQ to objects. But LINQ to SQL generates an SQL query from the code and so it doesn't need to use the methods.

Comment: @svick - Now I feel like a linq-to-objects fool. You are spot on.